# Dynamically switch between a textarea and a textbox in an asp:BoundField depending on the content length

Tags: asp.net, gridview

How can I dynamically switch between a text-box and a text-area in an asp:BoundField of a gridview when displaying text for editing depending on the length of the text content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this by css style,

aspx page:

```
<style type="text/css">
  #input
    {
        -moz-appearance: textfield;
        -webkit-appearance: textfield;
        background-color: white;
        background-color: -moz-field;
        border: 1px solid darkgray;
        font: -moz-field;
        font: -webkit-small-control;
        width: 250px;
    }
</style>
<body>
   <div>
    <asp:GridView ID="gv" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server"> 
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Text">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div id="input" contenteditable></div>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
</body>
```

aspx.cs Page :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindGrid();
        }
    }

    public void BindGrid()
    {
        List<string> lst = new List<string>();
        lst.Add("Name1");
        lst.Add("Name2");
        gv.DataSource = lst;
        gv.DataBind();
    }
```

otherwise onkeypress event we can check the lenght of the textbox string and if length exceeds one line, then we can change the css. Hope this will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

On data bound event of gridview , check the length of content and then change the TextMode of asp:textbox to multiline for textarea and singleine for textbox